# Rupee symbol not displaying in android

Tags: android

in adapter -

```
holder.amount.setText("" + R.string.Rs + wallet.getAmount());
```

strings.xml -

```
<string name="Rs">\u20B9</string>
```

But it is displaying   2131230770 instead of Rupee syambol

Can someone help me how to get rupee symbol instead of  2131230770?

Comment: what if `getString(R.string.Rs)` instead of `R.string.Rs`

Comment: Its giving error can not resolve method getString(int)

Comment: `context.getString(R.string.Rs);`. you should have context in your adapter class

Comment: Its works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use the integer ID of your String resource, instead of loading it. 
You should use the following:

```
Context.getString(R.id.Rs);
```

This requires the use of a Context object, so make sure you can reach it in your viewholder.